# Drupal 7 Views Chart Statistics Over Time

Tags: 7, views, charts

I want to create a View of node requests/views over time. The problem is grouping the Access log timestamps (minute,hour,day, etc) so that these are chartable. Does anybody know of a solution for this in Drupal 7 Views 3?

Comment: Any news/feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Within the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, there is an interesting issue about this, i.e. [Graph node input over time (support date formatting on a continuous axis)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096). In [Comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) of that issue is stated: 'The trouble here is that neither Views nor Date modules provide aggregation options for date-based fields.'. The patch(es) included in this issue are expected to soon be applied.